# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пробую набросать программу для парсинга информации с сайта с курсом валют, не могу понять в чем ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Data():
    btc = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/'
    ether = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/currencies/ethereum/historical-data/'
    ltc = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/currencies/litecoin/historical-data/'
    dash = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/currencies/dash/historical-data/'
    eos = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/currencies/eos/historical-data/'
    all_links = [btc, ether, ltc, dash, eos]
    price_list = [[], [], [], [], []] 
    date_list = [[], [], [], [], []]
    current_price = [] 
    vocabulary = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_history(self.all_links) 
    def get_html(self, url): 
        r = requests.get(url)  
        return r.text

    def get_history(self, all_links): 
        k = 0
        for i in all_links:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(self.get_html(i), 'lxml') 
            table = soup.find_all('tr', class_='text-right') 
            self.current_price.append(float(str((soup.find('span', class_='h2')).text)))
            for j in table:
                td = j.find_all('td')
                self.date_list[k].insert(0, td[0].text)
                self.price_list[k].insert(0, float(td[1].text))
                self.vocabulary[k][td[0].text] = td[1].text
            k += 1
```

Comment: у тебя text пустой, код я тебе не могу скинуть, питон не особо знаю

Comment: Очевидно, `soup.find('span', class_='h2')` не находит никакого элемента по заданному критерию и возвращает `None`.

Comment: Я проверил ваш код, никакой ошибки у меня не было.